# Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /posts/[slug]

Tags: next.js

I have the following [slug].js file in my project:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import PostContent from "../../components/posts/post-detail/post-content";
import { getPostByName, getAllPosts } from "../../helpers/api-util";

function PostDetailPage(props) {
  const post = props.selectedPost;
  console.log(post);
  if (!post) {
    return (
      <div className="">
        <p>Loading...</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <PostContent post={post.slug} />;
}


export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const blogSlug = context.params.slug;
  const post = await getPostByName(blogSlug);
  return {
    props: {
      selectedPost: post,
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const posts = await getAllPosts();
  const paths = posts.map(post => ({ params: { blogSlug: post.slug } }));

  return {
    paths: paths,
    fallback: "blocking",
  };
}

export default PostDetailPage;
```

This is my file structure:

[image]

I am getting my data from firebase with the following data structure:

[image]

The idea is that when I click my post on the 'all posts' page, I get into the PostContent component that contains all my post info.

Once I try to click on a particular post, I am getting the error mentioned in the subject.

`Slug` is not a string so I am not entirely sure why I am getting this.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have mismatch between filename dynamic key and what you expect in the code.

You return `blogSlug` key in `getStaticPaths`:

```js
const paths = posts.map(post => ({ params: { blogSlug: post.slug } }));
```

but your file is named `[slug].js` and you expect a `slug` key here in `getStaticProps`:

```js
const blogSlug = context.params.slug;
```

It should be consistent, in this case it should be named `slug` everywhere.

Comment: Facing same error in my case even when it's correctly named.

Comment: In my case, it works only as `const paths = res.data.map(course => `/course/${course.id}`)`, without the params, I must be using a newer/older version.

Answer (score 0):

A string is expected for slug, so just wrap the generated value in String():

```
String(post.slug)
```